# How to filter special characters and letters using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a problem with my code I have a validation. I have an existing validation that can validate letters and special characters in the textfield that prevent the user from typing letters and special characters.

And I want to include that validation with my code but I dont know how.

Here's a bit of my code:

```
<input type="text" class="col-md-5 quantity text-center" id="base_<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $product['quantity']; ?>" required="required" onKeyup="setQty(<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>);" />&nbsp;pcs.
```

...
This is the javascript validation

```
function setQty(id) {
        //validate if have a value and the value is not equal to 0
        if($("#base_"+id).val().length > 0 && $("#base_"+id).val() != 0){
            alert("YES");
        } else {
            alert("NO");
        }

}
```

And this is the existing function that can validate the letters and special char.

```
$(".quantity").keypress(function (e) {
        //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
        if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
            //display error message
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I want to include that in my if statement. But I dont have an idea.
Can you give me a more simple solution for this?

Ok that's all thanks.

Comment: This fiddle from Gagan_Gami will give you a start - http://jsfiddle.net/Gagan_Gami/nSjy7/333/

Comment: Ok thanks for some suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

JQuery has a lot of plugins for this, like the [masked input plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/).
You'll have to 'import' the code of it, and use it, like

```
$("#quantity").mask("99");
```

And you can customize the placeholder, for example (it's all in the documentation):

```
$("#quantity").mask("99", {placeholder:" "});
```

Since it's a product quantity, I assumed it wont pass two digits. That's the advantage of using this plugin.

---

Other solution is using html 5, with the [number input](http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-input-types/#input-number). It's pretty simple, actually. You said you want something more simple, so I recommend this one:

```
<input type='number' .../>
```